# Why do some bad relative URLs work?

Tags: html, relative-path

Some images that look like they shouldn't work (bad relative URLs), are being displayed in the browsers.

For example, on this page:

http://www.jbprince.com/pastry-bags-tips-and-brushes/pastry-tube-set-55-pc.asp

This image is displayed correctly:

```
<img src="images/B603A.jpg"/>
```

By my reckoning, the absolute path should be:

```
http://www.jbprince.com/pastry-bags-tips-and-brushes/images/B603A.jpg
```

which doesn't resolve. But it displays in the browser, and if you click "copy image URL" it shows:

```
http://www.jbprince.com/images/B603A.jpg
```

Shouldn't images be a subdirectory of pastry-bags-tips-and-brushes as there is no preceding slash? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note this line in the `<head>`:

`<base href="http://www.jbprince.com/">`

So this is not a bad link, since

`<img src="images/B603A.jpg"/>`

is appended to the base (see [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)), thus results in

`http://www.jbprince.com/images/B603A.jpg`

Comment: Solved in 5 mins. I ♥ StackOverflow. Thanks @Ziyao @evil otto.

Answer (score 0):

The page has a base url set (with the base element in the head section), which changes how relative links/images/... are resolved.